# Validate token of Android and iOS notifications - PHP

Tags: php, android, ios, push-notification

I've a system developed in PHP to send push notifications to Android and iOS devices, and i need to check if the token associated to that device still valid or not!

Every time the user opens the app, it registers a token in the database if is not there already, but as much as i know, tokens are changed often!

So for the same device i can have more than one token associated, and they are not valid anymore.

Is there anyway to check it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For that you must update device token while user login or register

Comment: Every time your app come from the background mode to active mode you need to call `webservice` and In server side every time you need to update the `fresh token` with 'old token'.This is only the one way to you can manage validate token.

Comment: You can store the device token in Shared-Preferences/NSUserDefaults. If you receive the current token when the user opens your app, you first check if the token changed. If it changed, you can send the old and new token to the server, which should replace the old token with the new one in your database.